# Help Connecting Arduino Uno To Computer

Tags: arduino-uno

I am A Newbie to Arduino

I have a Windows 7 PC. Last Time I bought an Arduino Uno Clone but after working for a day, it stopped detecting on the port. So I bought a new Clone Of different brand. Now I Want in which sequence should I install its drivers, Coonect it, Unzip Arduino IDE...Reboot??

I dont want a problem this time. Another question is Should I first connect the clone and then Install its drivers Or first install drivers and then plug the board? When Is the reboot required?

Product Link : https://m.ebay.in/itm?itemId=121708881208

Please Explain...
Thanks In Advance

Comment: Tip: Don't buy an "Arduino" from someone that can't even spell "Cable".

Comment: In $US, they are selling it for $7.64. This is indeed cheap. In english, there is a phrase; `You get what you pay for`. This means in this context, you are paying for low quality. If you can, try to but the real thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have shorted my bords a few time and they always came back to "life" after a minute. Maybe you should be more concern about the voltage you supply to the board. Even if it can take up to 12 volt I never use more then 9 volt on the board. And if you run motors on them its always good to supply them with an external power source and use something like a H bridge to power your devices. I made mistakes and my board are still in mint conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to start by pointing out that you are using a clone. The arduino IDE by default does support clones. Just install your port drivers that's far enough.

The reason your board got spoilt the last time definitely was not cause you did not install the drivers in the right order. It could be due to many reasons, few listed below:

1. Poor PCB quality
2. Humidity
3. Cheap USB to UART converter.
4. Short circuit in your connection

So what I recommend is the either the use of genuine arduino boards if you can afford.

**Note:** Most likely its only the USB to UART (CH340G) that has been destroyed, you could buy a hot air station and replace the IC, it is a much cheaper solution.

Comment: The clone Uno probably cost $5. A hot air station would be more likely to be 10 to 20 times that much, plus you would need the replacement chip and considerable skill to change it over.

Comment: @NickGammon You do have a point, the only reason I recommended him to replace the IC was since he was getting into electronics he might as well learn to replace an IC. While we are here, have you had any experience with clones as to why the USB to UART chip tends to get fried easily?

Comment: No, I don't know that. Possibly they are manufactured "on the cheap" and have lower tolerances. It might save a hundredth of a cent to omit, for example, protection diodes. It seems to work, people buy it, and you can always blame "user error".

Comment: `I bought an Arduino Uno Clone` - strictly speaking it should be a "Xxxx brand: (Arduino-compatible)". There is only one Arduino Uno, and that is the official one made by Arduino. According to the [Arduino FAQ](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/FAQ) *"Arduino" is a trademark of Arduino LLC and should not be used for unofficial variants.*. If you mentioned the brand in your question, it might help other people's buying decisions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the link and the item is not available anymore. That way it is impossible to say which driver you should install.

I agree with the answers and comments so far, get the real board. I've heard of people who fried their USB ports because of Arduino clones and their terrible/absent circuit protection.

If you can't afford the original board, what will you do if it damages your computer?